# How to assign names to dynamically generated text boxes and retrieve their values?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, textbox

I have dynamically generated textboxes. I want to assign names and id to the textboxes and also retrieve the values of dynamically generated textboxes to insert into database. How can it be done?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<select id="sel2" multiple>
<option value="first">first option</option>
<option value="second">sec option</option>
<option value="third">third option</option>
<option value="fourth">fourth option</option>
<option value="fifth">fifth option</option>
<option value="sixth">six option</option>
</select>


<table id="tab2">
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

<button id="add" value="Add">Add</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#add").click(function()
{
    var selectval = $('#sel2').val();

    var len = selectval.length;

    for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
        $("#tab2 tbody").append("<tr><td>"+selectval[i]+"</td><td><input type='text'</td></tr>");
    }

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: The HTML you're appending is broken.  It ought to read `<input type="text" />` to be sensible at least.  Is there any reason you can't just say `<input type="text" id="textbox"' + i + '" />"`; your textboxes would then have IDs corresponding to your iteration point, just like `selectval[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below , It will help you...

```
$("#tab2 tbody").append("<tr><td>"+selectval[i]+"</td><td><input type='text' id='text" + i + "' /></td></tr>");
```

It will generate Id like text0, text1, text2...

To **Get the value** from the Text box add the below codes and try it...

Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/RDz5M/4/

**HTML :**

```
<button id="Get" value="Get">Get</button>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$("#Get").click(function(){
$('#tab2 tr').each(function(){
    $("#divResult").html($("#divResult").html() + ($(this).find("input[id^='text']").val()) + "<br>")
});
});
```

Comment: hey thanks @Pandian its done now...pls help  how to retrieve the values of those dynamically generated table rows in the above code in jsp, in order to insert into database...

Comment: hey @Pandian..pls help me for the above code..Each time wen i select multiple items then only textboxs of order text0,text1,tex2...are generated..but for each single item if i select n click the button its generating  only text0 each time..n also i want to reterive the values of the generated fields...how it can be done..?

Comment: @Atit: I have added the Value Retrieve Codes, try it now, See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RDz5M/4/